# How to implement oop solution for menu

Tags: oop

can u suggest a oo design for this problem:

need to implememt a menu.

the menu has n options: (from 0-n)

- 0 - is exit from current level into the last level.
- [1-n] are actions.

action can be:

1) open a new sub menu with the same behavior.

2) execution a task (lets say with by interface contract named: doAction().

Comment: Are you interested in the possible approach itself or do you want an actual example? Mentioning the programming language you are using / willing to use would bring more specific answers

Answer (score 1):

So you need hierarchically organized "nodes" and each of them has some action associated with it. I would create such a single MenuItem model that contains all this behavior (in java):

```
public interface MenuItem {
    MenuItem parent();

    Iterable<MenuItem> children();

    String name();

    void proceed();
}
```

The 'parent()' and 'children()' methods navigate up or down the tree, name() is just a printable name of the node and proceed() actually runs a procedure. A possible implementation would be to encapsulate an XML document, which is hierarchical by design, with nodes containing names and ids and a map associating ids with actions, so something like the following code (in java):

```
public final class XmlMenuItem implements MenuItem {
    private final String id;
    private final Document xml;
    private final Map<String, Runnable> actions;

    public XmlMenuItem(String id, Document xml, Map<String, Runnable> actions) {
        this.id = id;
        this.xml = xml;
        this.actions = actions;
    }

    @Override
    public MenuItem parent() {
        Element parent = Element.class.cast(xml.getElementById(id).getParentNode());
        return new XmlMenuItem(parent.getAttribute("id"), xml, actions);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<MenuItem> children() {
        List<MenuItem> result = new ArrayList<>();
        NodeList children = xml.getElementById(id).getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
            result.add(new XmlMenuItem(Element.class.cast(children.item(0)).getAttribute("id"), xml, actions);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String name() {
        return xml.getElementById(id).getTextContent();
    }

    @Override
    public void proceed() {
        actions.get(id).run();
    }
}
```